# Can the umbilicus evert without an underlying umbilical hernia?

Tags: dermatology

Can the skin of the umbilicus detach from the abdominal wall (perhaps with trauma but without breakage of the skin) and will the umbilicus pop out if this happens?

I've tried looking for examples of this but I haven't found any publicly available clinical literature covering this possibility.

I'm aware that eversion can be used to treat things like pilonidal cysts around it which made me wonder if the pressure from the subcutaneous fat and fluids would flip the umbilicus inside out if it wasn't attached to the abdominal wall.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if this question is more suited to biology.se?

Comment: @DaveL Possibly.